# How do I access the data returned by REST API in date-value format?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rest

I am creating a Covid-Tracker app in Angular using an open REST API (https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/11144369/Szf6Z9B3?version=latest#a9a60f59-fde4-4e94-b1f1-a3cb92bd1046). 
 I would like to get the number of confirmed cases from the last 30 days in a given country. This is how the response looks like: 
 [image]

In Angular, I get the `cases` from the JSON response using this code:

`covid.service.ts`

```js
  getHistoricalData(country: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.URL}/historical/${country}`);
  }
```

`dashboard.component.ts`

```js
  this.covidService.getHistoricalData('poland').subscribe(res => {
      let cases = res.timeline.cases;
      console.log(cases);
  });
  }
```

And I get the following output in browser's console: 
[image]

However, I don't know how to save this output in a form of key-value pair, where *key* would be the date and *value* the number of cases on this day. I have tried using a `Map` but I don't know how to extract given date and the corresponding value. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iterate the keys of that object using Object.keys(your_object) as following,

```
// data is timeline.cases
let data = { "5/19/20": 100, "5/20/20": 200 };
let newArray = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    newArray.push({date: key, cases: data[key]});
});
console.log(newArray)
```

You can now access each date and its cases by a for loop on newArray.
Hope it helps !